# Errors vs Logs in rust

Tags: logging, rust, error-handling

Regarding Logs (for the programmers) and error types (such as enum which contains failure options), this is what I used too from my c++ projects:

Logs (such as syslogs):

1. Are for the programmers to debug and understand potential bugs-
2. usually contains file and line number to indicate where the log came from

Errors:

1. Are distinctive values which indicates different types of failures
2. Are for the code itself to have alternative handle in case of specific errors (example: `busy` error can be caught by the user, and the user can handle it with retry)
3. If the API fails on an internal logic, which the user has nothing to do with, return some kind of `InternalError`. That way you dont spam the user with irrelevant error types

The main thing to note here that logs are for the programmers to have a better information of what went wrong, and errors are for the code for alternative solution in case of a failure. Logs and errors are separate and not the same thing.

My question is about rust error handling and logging. In rust to handle an error we create enum of possible failure scenarios. In most cases I would also be required to implement `Display` trait (can be eased with `thiserror` but I will still have to provide a string for each error).

What is the idea behind having a string for error? Is it for user application logs? is it for the programmer logs?
Things doesn't add up for me if it is for the programmer logs:

1. At the beginning of the post I described why logs != errors. But in this case, because I have to implement log for each error, I also have to publicly announce each internal error I have, which contradicts "Errors 3." point I described earlier
2. Programmer logs also have additional information such as log timestamp, file and line number. I don't know if the string in the error can have that information, but even if it does it seems like a weird way of doing so

What are the realationship between the string of the error and the error itself?

Comment: Consider receiving a `std::io::Error` when writing a file. There are potentially some error conditions that you can handle but probably many others that you cannot. In the latter case, why should the error not be self-describing so you can put it in a log message?

Comment: Rust is nothing unusual here. In many other languages errors are reported as _exceptions_, and those exception types usually have a way to get a descriptive string: in Java `Throwable.getMessage()`; in C++ `std::exception::what()`; in C# `Exception.message; in Javascript `Error.message`...

Answer (score 0):

> At the beginning of the post I described why logs != errors. But in this case, because I have to implement log for each error, I also have to publicly announce each internal error I have, which contradicts "Errors 3." point I described earlier

For libraries, it is important to distinguish between different kinds of errors. Perhaps this specific error is not important and can be ignored. Perhaps the operation can be retried. Perhaps we know how to handle it. Libraries usually hand the errors to their callers, and let them decide what to do with them. There your errors point 3 does not apply.

In applications, however, this is indeed many times not important. In those cases, you can avoid the boilerplate of defining a custom error type and just use a generic one, such as [`Box<dyn Error>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/error/trait.Error.html), or libraries that are essentially "better `Box<dyn Error>`", such as [`anyhow`](https://docs.rs/anyhow) or [`eyre`](https://docs.rs/eyre)).

As for whether they represent logs or errors, error values in Rust somewhat try to be both. Think about them as error *conditions*, not error *reports*. They represent that an error has occurred. Some error. What to do with it - this is up to you. You can log it (usually using the `Debug` representation which is intended for programmers, which errors should implement) and/or you can report them to the user, either tell them the specific error that has occurred (usually via the `Display` representation, which errors also should implement) or just as a generic "An error occurred" message.

Comment: `Think about them as error conditions, not error reports. They represent that an error has occurred. Some error. What to do with it - this is up to you. You can log it` - Programmer logs often contains more data like timestamp, file and the line which the error occurred. I is hard to build proper log from it. It seems to me that I can just ignore the string for the errors, and handle logging myself

Comment: @UdiM Errors, for example with `anyhow`, can capture backtraces.